# Magento2 + Custom option price not included in price sorting

Tags: magento2, price, custom-options, product-listing, price-sorting

By default magento include minimum price from custom option in product listing price sorting but in my case this functionality isn't working.

any one have idea which settings i need to update?

```
I'll try to explain...

Product 1: price 100 EUR
Product 2: price 90 EUR + 1 required custom option 20 EUR
Product 3: price 130 EUR

It should see like this:

Product 2: 100 EUR
Product 1: 90 EUR
Product 3: 130 EUR

but it's showing like this

Product 2: 90 EUR
Product 1: 100 EUR
Product 3: 130 EUR
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding these codes to app/design/frontend/theme_package/theme/layout/catalog.xml

```
<reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>

</reference>
```

Will it work in magento2?